# On Obtaining Positions in 2048

Tags: recreational-mathematics

2048 is played in a 4*4 space. At the start there are 2 tiles spawned.

Move - a swipe followed by a new tile (either 2 or 4) spawning.

Position - any configuration of the various tiles and blanks on the board.

End Position - a position where no moves are possible (must have either 2 or 4 on one of outer 12 blocks to be obtainable)

Valid Position - obtainable through play.

Invalid Position - unobtainable through play. (all 2's)

> For a given position **p** and natural number **n**, let $n(p)$ be the number of *possible positions* **n** moves earlier. Let $n^+(p)$ be the sum of all the different *ways* of each position from n(p) to reach position **p**.

Note that $n^+(p) \geq n(p)$; there are two ways figure 1 could transpose to figure 2.
[image]

figure1______________________________figure2

Example where $1(p) = 1^+(p)$: [image]

> **Is it possible to backtrack from a valid position and get an invalid position?** If so, can n(p) not increase when add 1 to **n**?
>
> How to tell valid positions from invalid?

Comment: You forgot to explain a main element of the rules, that a move involves swiping a number onto an adjacent equal number, resulting in a tile with the double value.

Comment: It's very inopportune to have $n$ and $\mathbf n$ denote two different things -- there are so many letters available, why reuse the same one?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Obviously there's an algorithmic way to calculate these functions; just check all possible ancestor positions. Are you looking for any particular properties in the algorithm?